# Old gas in 2 cycle engine

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, gasoline, two-stroke

I have a 2 stroked engine that sat for over 2 years. I drained the gas and can get it to turn over when I put starter fluid in the carb. it is blowing out a water substance from the muffler and cuts off after 5 seconds. Is this just the engine clearing he old gas or the sign of another issue?

Comment: I would say keep trying. You might want to run the oil concentrate a little bit richer, like at 1:45 or something on first startup ... though that would be hard to measure out. Did you pull the plug and see if it was clean? Like I said though, just keep tugging. It may take a bit. I don't know what water would be doing in the exhaust, though.

Answer (score 9):

Gasoline sitting for two years in the float bowl of a carburetor will surely lead to some varnish.  The hydrocarbons evaporate from the fuel and oxygen acts as an oxidation catalyst changing the remaining components into other compounds leaving varnish in their wake.

Varnish will coat and clog the inside of the carburetor.  Float bowl, floats, needle and seat as well as any jets the were submerged in the gas.

I would suggest at the very least you remove the carburetor from the motorcycle and take the float bowl off.  Get some carb cleaner with the little red straw/hose that you can use to spray into jets and and orifices of the carburetor.  Let it sit, do it again and use a bowl to capture the runoff.  You can let the carb sit in the bowl for a bit if there are trouble spots.  Use a toothbrush.  Get a thin piece of copper wire you can stick into any jets to ensure they are not clogged.  Those are your real trouble areas.  Take your time.  Be thorough or you will have to do it again.

If you have some extra carb cleaner you can spray it around inside your fuel tank.

Replace your fuel filter.  They are cheap.

If the bike runs with starter fluid, you have compression and spark.  The last piece is fuel delivery.  Focus on that and you will be victorious.

The previous suggestion of a little more oil in the gas initially is good advice.  Your bottom end needs lubrication and if your start it without lubrication you can damage your offset journal and main journal bearings on your crank.

Best of luck.